# How to save data directly from the migration file in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

In my ROR project, I came across an issue. Previous developer of the project has save an array of data into a single column for a particular field. But now I have to get those data and save it to another separate table with the current table id. Following is my code for get the details from the db:

```
@ar = AResponse.select("id, selected_barriers");
    @ar.each do |p|
      p.selected_barriers.each do |barrier|

      end
    end
```

What I wanted is I have to save the `p.id` and `barrier` to  a new table and I have to do it in a migration file. So when the migration runs, it will get all the existing details from `AResponse` and save it to the new one. Can I do it only with migration file? If so how can I do it?

This is my full code

I tried but its not working: Following is my code

```
class AnalysisBarriers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up

  end

  def change
    create_table :analysis_barriers do |t|
      t.integer :analysis_response_id, :null => false
      t.string :barrier
    end
    @analysis_response = AnalysisResponse.select("id, selected_barriers");
    @analysis_response.each do |p|
      p.selected_barriers.each do |barrier|
        AnalysisBarriers.create(:analysis_response_id => p.id, :barrier => barrier)
      end
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :analysis_barriers
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a model for this other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do data changes after migrations. Whatever data changes you want to do, you can do in change function or up function. Take the following example

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table events do |t|
      t.datetime :starts_at
      t.datetime :ends_at
      t.timestamps
    end
    Event.create(:starts_at => Time.now, :ends_at => Time.now+1)
  end
end
```

Above statement will add data to your table just after its creation.

Comment: I have already created the new table and migrated to the database. So in my new migration can I just run my above code in the migration? Also I dont have a model for this migration yet

Comment: No problem, migrations have nothing to do with models, you can create new migration for putting data in table in this way.

Comment: I'm gonna do it now, I'll let u know :)

Comment: Please check my question again, I added my whole code as u've mentioned but its not working :(

Comment: This is the error: `uninitialized constant CreateAnalysisBarriers`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I separately put my create code in a new migration file but the same kinda way as you've mentioned in above and now its working perfectly. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry can't notice your comment. Anyways thats gr8 :).